# Protocol Extensions with Selectors in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to extend a Protocol in Swift by adding a registerGestureRecognizers function. Here is the complete implementation.

The FilterableView is used by classes that inherit from UIImageView.

```
import UIKit

protocol FilterableView : class  {

    var name :String { get }
    var view :UIImageView { get } 

    func applyFilter(originalImage :UIImage) -> UIImage
}

extension FilterableView {

    func registerGestureRecognizers() {

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Self.filterTapped(_:)))

    }

    func filterTapped(recognizer :UITapGestureRecognizer) {
            print("filter Tapped")
    }

}
```

At this line:

```
 let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Self.filterTapped(_:)))
```

I get the following message:

```
Argument of '#selector' refers to a method that is not exposed to Objective-C
```

What am I missing?

I added the @objc keyword but same issues.

[image]

UPDATE 2:

Now, I have problem in my classes that are conforming to the FilterableView protocol. Xcode is complaining that I must implement the filterTapped function in my classes, even though I have provided the implementation in the protocol extension method.

Comment: You're adding the wrong function to your protocol.  You should be adding `func filterTapped(recognizer :UITapGestureRecognizer)`

Comment: Yes and for some reason you changed `#selector(Self.filterTapped(_:))` into this `#selector(filterTapped)` Please don't change the correct part of the code.

Comment: try `FilterableView.filterTapped(_:)`

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Re your edit: you added the wrong function to your protocol.  Add `func filterTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)` not `func registerGestureRecognizers()`.

```
@objc protocol FilterableView: class  {

    var name: String { get }
    var view: UIImageView { get }

    func applyFilter(originalImage: UIImage) -> UIImage
    func filterTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
}

extension FilterableView {

    func registerGestureRecognizers() {

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Self.filterTapped(_:)))

    }

    func filterTapped(recognizer :UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("filter Tapped")
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do I even need to put anything in the protocol? Why can't they be just in the protocol extensions.

Comment: @johndoe The protocol extension isn't implicitly exposed to Objective-C.  That's why your need to declare it in the `@objc` protocol.

Comment: Even if I expose filterTapped in the protocol and even though I have implementation of filterTapped in the protocol extension. The concrete classes still complain if I do not implement filterTapped function.